# convert single index pandas data frame to multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, multi-index

I have a data frame with following structure:

```
df.columns
Index(['first_post_date', 'followers_count', 'friends_count',
       'last_post_date','min_retweet', 'retweet_count', 'screen_name',
       'tweet_count',  'tweet_with_max_retweet', 'tweets', 'uid'],
        dtype='object')
```

Inside the *tweets* series, each cell is another data frame containing all the *tweets* of an user.

```
df.tweets[0].columns
Index(['created_at', 'id', 'retweet_count', 'text'], dtype='object')
```

I want to convert this data frame to a multi-index frame, essentially by breaking the cell containing tweets. One index will be the *uid*, and another will be the *id* inside *tweet*.

How can I do that?

[link to sample data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uaki7ks6gv01ie/sample.json?dl=0)

Comment: Could you do something like `df_tweets = {'created_at' : a, 'id' : b, 'retweet_count' : c, 'text : d1` then for your main `df` do `df = {... 'tweets' : df2' ...}`? I misunderstood what you were asking disregard this.

Comment: Can you post the sample data?

Comment: @AndrewL, I added sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from df, you have tweets columns which contain df of tweets, so I create a `tweets_df` dataframe and concat all the df in tweets to `tweets_df`, add uid column to know which uid that tweet belong to, then merge info of uid to `tweets_df` for further process if needed. Please comment if you need further modification. It is hard to get your sample data and convert to json. So I did this on guessing, hope it still gives you some ideas.

```
import pandas as pd

df = .... #your df

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame() #create blank df to contain tweets

# explode tweets to df
## loop each uid
for uid in df['uid']:
    temp = df.loc[df['uid']==uid, :] # select df by uid
    temp = temp['tweets'].iloc[0] # select tweets column -> df
    temp['uid'] = uid # add uid column to know tweets belong to which uid
    tweets_df = pd.concat([results, temp], ignore_index=True) # concat to container df

# get a uid info df from starting df
uid_info_column = df.columns
uid_info_column.remove('tweets')
uid_info_df = df.loc[:, uid_info_column]


# merge info on uid with tweets_df
final = pd.merge(left=tweets_df, right=uid_info_df, on='uid', how='outer')
```